# How to add description on Google search for a Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I am hosting a shiny app on shinyapps.io. I am wondering how I can get the app to have a description when searched in google. In my dashboard body I added the head tag and nested the description meta tag with no luck.

```
dashboardBody( 
 tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css"),
           tags$meta(name="description",
           content = "Caribou Webtools are designed to support the conservation and reporting of 
                      caribou habitat conditions within the A La Peche, Little Smoky, Narraway
                      and Redrock-Praire Creek herds. The webtools are built for biologists, 
                      planners and managers to run caribou resource selection, predation, and 
                      connectivity models at the population-scale. The built-in Disturbance 
                      Dashboard provides visualization and reporting metrics on the percent 
                      disturbance (including a 500m buffer) at the population-scale.")),
```

Comment: You need to allow a few days before Google updates the search results.

Comment: I made the description update 2 weeks ago, and still nothing.